# How to make Turkish coffee in a syphon?

Tags: extraction, turkish-coffee, syphon

I've been experimenting with my Syphon to make turkish coffee, my thoughts on the matter are that using the syphon without a filter would allow the water to boil, move to the upper chamber, let the vapor out, move back to the lower chamber and then boil up again... making it easy to do the three boils required for the turkish coffee. (plus it allows me to get around my lack of a proper Cezve)

However, I've been unable to find information in Google about using this approach to turkish coffee. So Im opening this question seeking to find information on using this approach, I would like to know if anyone else has experience doing something like this, or any online sources about it?

Comment: Interesting. I would say, just do it once and see for yourself if the result is encouraging. And don't forget to report it to us :-)

Comment: I've done it a few times, some times using a metal filter and other times using no filter at all. The feeling that Im getting is that the way the siphon moves the water up and down doesn't let the coffee settle to the bottom properly. I'll continue experimenting. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I, being a native Turkish and experienced Turkish coffee drinker for my life, quite conservative about this.

There will be some major problems on producing the genuine Turkish-style with a syphon.

1. The extraction process is made by heat, not by pressure in Turkish coffee. So, syphon is not what it is intended for.
2. Two (or even three) times is quite correct during preparation. But boiling is quite wrong. Never boil Turkish coffee.
3. A well-prepared Turkish coffee is layered. So, the grounded coffee subside at the bottom of the "fincan" (cup). Ideally, it never gets mixed in the drinkable layer of the coffee. (Those remaining grounded coffee is for the fortunetellers.) I assume, by moving coffee in between the chambers of syphon three times, you cannot settle the grounded coffee easily. So, it will fill into your mouth. This is undesirable.

Comment: Actually all very good points. Welcome to Coffee SE! Incidentally, how do you regulate these 'two or three times'? I just stopped attempting that anymore. Also, I think it's worth pointing out that the grounds in a cezve set even though you stir it during the heating (if that's right -- at least I've just made Turkish 5 min ago, with stirring, and it is quite admirable).

Comment: Normally, there must be hardly any grounds left in the cezve after you fill your fincan. Before you drink your coffee, you normally wait about a minute or two. So the coffee in the fincan settles down. This settlement happens in two ways. First, the temperature decreases to a more natural degree so you can drink it comfortably. Second*, the coffee granules move to the bottom so you can drink just the extracted coffee from the top.

(*) If this settlement never occurs, then you have made something wrong. This layered structure is also an indicator of good preparation.

Comment: Right, I see. I guess it is the way it works for me -- much grounds sitting at the bottom of the cup. As to the triple heating, maybe I'll ask a proper question here first -- will that work for you?

Comment: I realize after some months that I've promised to delete the above comment and explain how to brew Turkish coffee by triple heating, I think I've done that long ago in [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/triple-heating-of-the-turkish-coffee), but forgot to mention it under this discussion. Sorry if somebody follows here. And after all these months, I keep the comment above.